# Cannot access a web site via https using a mobile device (Windows and Android)

Tags: server

Since this morning, I cannot reach my server webpage using any mobile device,  have no problem  accessing via PC.

- htaccess force https
- the certificate is SHA1 valid until 2015
- SSL disabled and TLS enabled
- No problem connecting via PC
- Problems accessing via smartphone (Android and Windows)
- No problem connecting using Iphone
- no info into Apache log
- no info into error log
- last month I applyed the poodle patch
- I'm testing a simple page with an OK output
- No error on the output page only a "page not available try later or refresh message"

Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was in the SSLCipherSuite, to resolve the poodle bug, as suggested, I had to disable the SSL protocol and modify the SSLCipherSuite.
The used SSLCipherSuite miss the Windows mobile and explorer 11 code, so i resolved using an updated SSLCipherSuite.

In the linked article mozilla suggest 3 different SSLCipherSuite based on browsers legacy compatibility.

here the solution:
https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Server_Side_TLS#Apache

Comment: Please avoid pure link answers. If the page you're linking to is moved or removed, the answer is useless. Can you add some details from the solution to your answer?